# System Service Not available Exception SimpleAdapter Android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, simpleadapter

Hello I am currently in the process of an application developed on Android, the principle is simple: Parsing an XML file, and then fill in the information in a listview.

I understand how to parse my XML file, but I'm stuck on creating the listview ..
I think I look at all the tutorials on filling listview x) Only I can not fit the tutorials on my application because I have a navigation tab so with fragments.

I often saw the need to establish a simpleAdapter and used the layout "simple_list_item_2". but I do not understand how this system.

Here is my code who parses my info in an ArrayList:

```
public class ListParseAdapter extends ListActivity{

    String data;
    String URL = "";
    String ITEM = "item";
    String TITRE = "title";
    String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    String LIEN = "link";
    final String[] fromMapKey =  {"TITRE", "DESCRIPTION"};
    final int[] toLayoutId = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
    HashMap<String, String> map;


    public ListParseAdapter(String pUrl) {
        URL = pUrl;
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void chargement(){

        XMLParser file = new XMLParser();
        data = file.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
        Document doc = file.getDomElement(data);
        NodeList NbItem = doc.getElementsByTagName(ITEM);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 1; i < NbItem.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            Element e = (Element) NbItem.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TITRE, file.getValue(e, TITRE));
            map.put(DESCRIPTION, file.getValue(e, DESCRIPTION));
            map.put(LIEN, file.getValue(e, LIEN));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,R.layout.simple_list_item_2, fromMapKey, toLayoutId);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

My Fragment_agenda.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="290dp" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my Fragment_agenda.java:

```
    public class AgendaFragment extends Fragment{

    private Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String url = "***********************";

            ListParseAdapter agenda = new ListParseAdapter(url);
            agenda.chargement();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agenda, container, false);

        task.run();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

With this code, I have an exception `System Service Exception Not available` and I think it can come from this line:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,R.layout.simple_list_item_2, fromMapKey, toLayoutId);
```

I also tried replacing the layout `simple_list_item_2` by mine (`Fragment_agenda.xml`) it's not working

I did not put my class to parse XML because I know it works I've done tests before
My logcat :

```
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765): Process: app6tem.infolonde, PID: 19765
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4543)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.<init>(SimpleAdapter.java:85)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at app6tem.adapter.ListParseAdapter.chargement(ListParseAdapter.java:59)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at app6tem.infolonde.AgendaFragment$1.run(AgendaFragment.java:30)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at app6tem.infolonde.AgendaFragment.onCreateView(AgendaFragment.java:42)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2552)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5088)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
05-28 15:55:09.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19765):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

Comment: Post your LogCat with that Exception

Comment: Done, i added the logcat

Comment: Whats line 42 on `AgendaFragment`? Is that the SimpleAdapter line?

Comment: task.run(); So I think is inside the run

Comment: And line 59 on `ListParseAdapter` is the `SimpleAdapter` line?

Comment: Also you are extending ListActivity, where is your onCreate()?

Comment: Yes, and i don't have the OnCreate();

Comment: In order to display an Activity you need an onCreate with your view. The error says it "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()" The answer below is correct

Answer (score 1):

```
ListParseAdapter extends ListActivity
```

```
ListParseAdapter agenda = new ListParseAdapter(url);
agenda.chargement();
```

Never instantiate activities with `new`. They won't be set up for anything useful.

Looks like `ListParseAdapter` should not be an activity at all. Remove the `extends ListActivity`. Where you need a `Context`, pass it in as a method argument. In a fragment, use `getActivity()` to get a reference to the hosting activity that you can use as a `Context`.

Comment: But if I remove new, how i can initialize my constructor ?

Comment: You can use `new`, just don't use it with activity classes.

Comment: for me, ListParseAdapter is not a activity I think. And extends ListActivity is for try to fill the listview,
I don't understand anything...